# How to loop through an IObservable containing an IEnumerable in C#?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to get a list of paired bluetooth devices using C#, the method used returns an IObservable collection containing IEnumerable objects which contain Bluetooth Device objects.
The compiler marks the variable assigned the return type of this method as `IObservable<IEnumerable<IDevice>>`. I am trying to access the `IDevice` from the collection. The documentation of the method suggests the use of a `Subscribe()` method to iterate through the collection but I do not know if this `Subscribe()` method needs some external trigger

```
List<string> devNames= new List<string>();
//I have tested the line below and it returns true so its not a permission issue
if (adapter.CanViewPairedDevices())
{
//here is my device collection variable
IObservable<IEnumerable<IDevice>> devices =adapter.GetConnectedDevices();
//here is how I try to get device names from the above collection
devices.Subscribe(deviceResult =>
       {
         foreach(var device in deviceResult){
                        devNames.Add(device.Name);
                                            }
       });
}
//devNames is still empty at this point
```

My list of names is empty at the end of the method call, does `Subscribe` need some kind of trigger ?
Is there an alternative way of iterating through such a type that will result in  names being added to the list?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=net-6.0. The 'Subscribe' method is used to register an observer that wants to receive notifications.

Comment: Yes subscribe is like registering to an event. There should be a Refresh or something on the adapter i guess.

Comment: @Firo, let me check if there is a refresh method

Comment: @TechGeek Please [edit] your question to include the exact type of your variable `adapter`?

Comment: I assume that `bNames` is `devNames`?

Comment: @Progman, yeah right away

Comment: @Enigmativity, yeah it was a typo , corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
IList<string> devNames =
    adapter
        .GetConnectedDevices()
        .SelectMany(devices => devices.Select(device => device.Name))
        .ToList()
        .Wait();
```

That will block on the observable which may not be desirable, so you can also await this code and make it asynchronous. Try this:

```
IList<string> devNames = await
    adapter
        .GetConnectedDevices()
        .SelectMany(devices => devices.Select(device => device.Name))
        .ToList();
```

You could use `.Subscribe(...)` but you wouldn't populate the `List<string> devNames` in the subscription. Using Rx, like I have above, you end up with an observable returns your `IList<string>`, so in the subscription you would need to know what you want to do with the list. You haven't said that in the question, so I can't answer that.

Comment: @Trying this out, hold your horses

Comment: code is fine and does not show any compile time errors, just debugged to check if its gonna work in the app

Comment: @TechGeek - The code is fine. I checked it before posting. It's rare that I post code without testing it.

Answer (score 1):

`devNames` variable is not part of your code snippet but I assume it is declared somewhere prior to this snippet execution.

The nature of `Subscriptions` is that they are `async`.
`devices.Subscribe` executes syncronously but the code within the subscription:

```cs
foreach(var device in deviceResult)
{
    devNames.Add(device.Name);
}
```

will execute at a later point, meaning that synchronous code after `devices.Subscribe` might not be able to see the results.

You can add your logic that references `devNames` within the subscription as well to resolve this issue.

```cs
List<string> bNames= new List<string>();
//I have tested the line below and it returns true so its not a permission issue
if (adapter.CanViewPairedDevices())
{
    //here is my device collection variable
    var devices =adapter.GetConnectedDevices();
    //here is how I try to get device names from the above collection
    devices.Subscribe(deviceResult =>
    {
        foreach(var device in deviceResult)
        {
            devNames.Add(device.Name);
        }
        // devNames is available here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out please I think it will work with you

```
 devNames = observable.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: it does not work, what is the type of observable please?

Comment: I'm using ConcurrentObservableCollection

Comment: This doesn't work as it is not an observable. The OP gave the correct signature.